# Highlight Text on JTextArea

Tags: java, loops, highlight

I need to highlight text on a JTextArea Im using JTextField to get users input and then a Button to grab the JTextFields text. Ultimately I need to make it so it highlights all occurrences of the String in JTextArea exp: I have 200 words and 10 occurrences of the word 'dog' I want dog to be highlighted 10 times.

I seem to be having a problem with the loop itself it highlights the first occurrence and then none after that.

```
    private void getSearch() throws BadLocationException {

                 // my textfield (searchT)
               String jtf = searchT.getText();

                // my jtextarea  (userField);
                String jta = userField.getText();

                hilit = userField.getHighlighter();
                hilit.removeAllHighlights();


         int index = jta.indexOf(jtf);

        while(index >=0){
        System.out.println("looping");

       int len = jtf.length();
        hilit.addHighlight(index,index+len, painter);
        index = jta.indexOf(jta, index+len);


    }

     }   




**PER REQUEST:**


public class project extend Frame implements ActionListener{

   Highlighter hilit;
   Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;



public project(){


     userField = new JTextArea();
     searchT = new JTextField("Spotlight");
     searchT.setEditable(true);
     searchT.setBorder(new LineBorder (Color.black));

     searchB = new JButton("Search");

        hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
        painter = new                    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);





// JButton (searchB) with ActionListener 
 searchB.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            searchBActionPerformed(evt);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DaWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

           private void searchBActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) throws BadLocationException  {
               Object sb = evt.getSource();
             if(searchB==sb){
           getSearch();

               }

           }
           private void getSearch() throws BadLocationException {

             // my jtextfield
           String jtf = searchT.getText();
            // my jtextarea
            String jta = userField.getText();

            hilit = userField.getHighlighter();
            hilit.removeAllHighlights();


     int index = jta.indexOf(jtf);

    while(index >=0){
    System.out.println("looping");


    System.out.println("im searching for"+index);
    int len = jtf.length();
    hilit.addHighlight(index,index+len, painter);
    index = jta.indexOf(jta, index+len);
    System.out.println("this is what I want to highlight"+ index);
    // remove hightlights with a timer for example after 10 seconds
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah do this search for the right string:

```
while(index >=0){
  System.out.println("looping");
  int len = jtf.length();
  hilit.addHighlight(index,index+len, painter);
  index = jta.indexOf(jtf, index+len);
}
```

--

I made a little program based on your code: the only problem is as I said that you were looking for the wrong string (you didnt change jta to jtf in indexOf(). Otherwise it works ok and highlights spotlight with red (my color you can set it to what you want):

```
class project extends Frame { // implements ActionListener{

 Highlighter hilit;
 Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;

JTextArea userField;
JTextField searchT;
JButton searchB;

public project(){


 userField = new JTextArea("spotlight aaa spotlight");
 searchT = new JTextField("spotlight");
 searchT.setEditable(true);
//     searchT.setBorder(new LineBorder (Color.black));

 searchB = new JButton("Search");

    hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
    painter = new                    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.red);





// JButton (searchB) with ActionListener 
 searchB.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        searchBActionPerformed(evt);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(DaWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }

       private void searchBActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) throws BadLocationException  {
           Object sb = evt.getSource();
         if(searchB==sb){
       getSearch();

           }

       }
       private void getSearch() throws BadLocationException {

         // my jtextfield
       String jtf = searchT.getText();
        // my jtextarea
        String jta = userField.getText();

        hilit = userField.getHighlighter();
        hilit.removeAllHighlights();


 int index = jta.indexOf(jtf);

while(index >=0){
System.out.println("looping");


System.out.println("im searching for"+jtf+" "+index);
int len = jtf.length();
hilit.addHighlight(index,index+len, painter);
index = jta.indexOf(jtf, index+len);
System.out.println("this is what I want to highlight"+ index);
// remove hightlights with a timer for example after 10 seconds
}

}

});

setSize(500, 500);

setLayout(new FlowLayout());

add(userField);
add(searchT);
add(searchB);

setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: This is producing the same result though, just one highlighted word on the JTextArea regardless if there is more than one occurrence of the String on the JTextArea

Comment: does it loop around correctly? do you get 10 "looping"?

Comment: no I'm not getting ten with this current method, i don't know  what I'm doing wrong here....

Comment: I've updated my code in the question area its located under ' per request' the code contains all the vars pertaining in relation to the the working code in question ( I did not copy all 2000 lines of that class as thats no fun ;) )  But essentially whats there is the code I'm working with relating to this particular problem

Comment: Thanks a lot works great... helps having another person looking over your work for the subtle things that are missed during long days :)